# XSD - unbound number of any (unkown) elements but last element in sequence is defined

Tags: java, xml, xsd, schema

Is it possible using one or more XSDs to validate the following xml structure

```
<container>
    <unkownA />
    <unkownB />
    <unkownC />
    ...
    <data />
</container>
```

by those rules

1. there is an unlimited number of unkown elements

   there is at least one of those unkown elements

   the last element is data

   data occurs only once

   data is validated according to provided rules

All the elements in the xml have the **same namespace ("")**, which we can't change.
We are most likely not able to **change the order of the elements** as well, though I know this is probably the easiest solution.
Changing the xml in general is not an viable option, since it is generated by a external system we don't control.

I tried something like this

```
<xs:sequence>
   <xs:any minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax" />
   <xs:element ref="data" minOccurs="1" />
</xs:sequence>
```

which of course, being ambiguous, violates the "Unique Particle Attribution".

I also read about the use of a second namespace here [Creating a 'flexible' XML schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592205)
but since we can't change the xml this does not seem to be a solution or I plainly don't understand it properly.

By the we are using Java to process the xml/xsd, the xsd **resides in the classpath**, so xs:import from within an xsd might be a problem.

If the answer is "This can't be done with xsd within these constraints" I'm fine with it.

So any ideas?

Comment: Do you have schemas for the 'unknown' datatypes?

Comment: @home: not at this point of the validation/in the schema that validates data, also they don't have to be validated at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked, even if it does not make me happy:

```
javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
        .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

schemaFactory
    .setFeature(
        "http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema-full-checking",
        false);
```

This seems to disable the validation of the schema itself.
The validation of the xml works as expected and described above.
And yes, I know: Disabling security/sanity features that are actived by default might not be a good idea. But till know there wasn't any time to find a better way.

Answer (score 1):

The schema that you tried is valid in XSD 1.1 - try it again, using the latest release of Saxon or Xerces.

Comment: the schema is valid in 1.0 as well. 
I spend some time integrating xerces 2.11.0 beta, but i not only got still the "Unique Particle Attribution" error, i also got an error which seems to be due to the beta state of the XSD 1.1 implementation:
`cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'doc'` - the declaration of doc is clearly there and works fine with the previous xml-api implementation

Comment: Currently I'm unable to get Saxon working within our project setup, when I do I'll report back and grant the answer state, if it works.

Comment: As it seems the home edition of Saxon does not contain the implementation of XSD 1.1, only the pro and enterprise version do.
So I'll have to get an evaluation license to do further testing.
This might take a while since the project of course goes on right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you at least knew the names of the types you were expecting to be in your container type then you could make them xs:anyType type. But you need to know the list of possible type names otherwise what is the point of a schema to define them?

UPDATE: I was incorrect, you can make the container `<xs:any/>` however this will prevent you from specifying that there must be a `<data />` element in the container.

Comment: the reason why we are trying to use a 'wildcard' is excatly that we don't know or want to know which elements might be contained in container, aside from data that is

Comment: Sorry my original answer was incorect. I have editted it. In your case your container needs to be made type xs:any. This means that the validator will ignore anything you put in there.